# How can I set refs and assign values to looped elements in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I am having trouble in setting the values to looped elements in React.js

What I am trying to achieve is, there's a list of items:

```
[{ id: 1, rate: 120 } ...]
```

I want to create 4 text boxes: Rate, Total Cost, Advance and Balance.

Total cost is calculated using the rate and another property from the object, size (rate * size).
Now, everytime rate changes, I want to calculate the total cost, and assign it to the respective row's total cost textbox.
Also, on first load, the textboxes should be pre-filled with these calculated values.

```
array.forEach((item) => {
  <div>
    <input type="text" ref/id={`item_r_${item.id}`} /> // Rate
    <input type="text" ref/id={`item_r_${item.id}`} /> // Total Cost
    <input type="text" ref/id={`item_r_${item.id}`} /> // Advance
    <input type="text" ref/id={`item_r_${item.id}`} /> // Balance
  </div>
})
```

How can I achieve this?

I've tried using refs but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution without using `refs`, it updates the value of `inputs` with their index.

**UPDATE**

Calculation of advance and balance is added in function `calculateBalance` and `onChangeAdv` respectively.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, rate: 120, size: 3, adv: 0 },
        { id: 2, rate: 150, size: 7, adv: 0 },
        { id: 3, rate: 180, size: 5, adv: 0 }
      ]
    };
  }
  onChange(e, i) {
    const data = [...this.state.data];
    data[i].rate = e.target.value;
    data.splice(i, 1, data[i]);
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  onChangeAdv(e, i) {
    const data = [...this.state.data];
    data[i].adv = e.target.value;
    data.splice(i, 1, data[i]);
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  calculateBalance(i) {
    let { data } = this.state;
    let bal = 0;
    bal = (data[i].rate * data[i].size) - data[i].adv;
    return bal;
  }

  render() {
    let { data, adv } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={item.rate}
                onChange={e => this.onChange(e, i)}
              />
              // Rate
              <input type="text" value={item.rate * item.size} /> // Total Cost
              <input type="text" value={item.adv} onChange={e => this.onChangeAdv(e, i)} /> // Advance
              <input type="text" value={this.calculateBalance(i)} /> // Balance
              <br />
              <br />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: although this solves the problem, I would need the "Advance" textbox to be editable so that when it is changed, the balance will be calculated (total cost - advance), it doesn't work in this case. Any ideas why?